# Prebid.js GPT integration: How GPT renders prebid winner

Tags: javascript, prebid.js, google-publisher-tag

I am trying to understand the rendering (final) flow:
In [Prebid.js Hello World example](https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/blob/master/integrationExamples/gpt/hello_world.html) there is simple integration:

1. Do not init GPT.
2. Make auction, select winner.
3. Set GPT targeting using winner details (price etc)
4. Refresh GPT, Ad Server trying to beat the price, on the success, it will send back a new winner creative. Most interesting is the case of fail - AdServer sends back some code with targeting, and as a result, I see the prebid winner rendered inside of GPT block.

I did search in prebid.js sources but there is no interaction between prebid.js and GPT after targeting/refresh. How GPT knows what it will render (and the ad content).

Answer (score 1):

When a header bidding bid wins auction in Google Ad Manager, GAM responds with the code which loops back to Prebid.js to render the creative. 
If you set up your Prebid creatives in the Ad Manager per [Prebid documentation](http://prebid.org/adops/step-by-step.html#step-2-add-a-creative) then the creative served on the page should look like this:

```
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prebid-universal-creative@latest/dist/creative.js"></script>
<script>
  var ucTagData = {};
  ucTagData.adServerDomain = "";
  ucTagData.pubUrl = "%%PATTERN:url%%";
  ucTagData.targetingMap = %%PATTERN:TARGETINGMAP%%;
  ucTagData.hbPb = "%%PATTERN:hb_pb%%";

  try {
    ucTag.renderAd(document, ucTagData);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
</script>
```

The code for `ucTag.renderAd` is available in the [Prebid Universal Creative repo](https://github.com/prebid/prebid-universal-creative/blob/master/src/creative.js). `renderAd()` for a desktop banner gets the Prebid internal ad ID from GAM targeting key-value (the *TARGETINGMAP* macro in the creative above) and renders the ad either by calling Prebid.js's [window.pbjs.renderAd()](https://github.com/prebid/prebid-universal-creative/blob/master/src/renderingManager.js#L76) or in a cross-origin scenario requests the ad from Prebid.js via [postMessage](https://github.com/prebid/prebid-universal-creative/blob/master/src/renderingManager.js#L139) and renders it inside a new iframe.